# Boolean method not retuning correct value

Tags: return, boolean

Ok so I think I'm being a noob because it's a new semester but the method "palindromeTest" always return's false even though the string is equal and the number is a palindrome. (A palindrome example is: (565) 677-6565) (also don't give me the answer outright I want to solve it on my own)

```
public class IjazZ_PhoneStringPalindrome
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    String phoneNumber;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter a phone number in this format (###) ###-####: ");
    phoneNumber = br.readLine();

    phoneNumber = justNumbers(phoneNumber);

    if (palindromeTest(phoneNumber))
    {
      System.out.println("This phone number is a palindrome!");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("This phone number is not a palindrome!");
    }

  }

  public static String justNumbers(String phoneNumber)
  {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(phoneNumber, " ()-");
    StringBuffer number = new StringBuffer();

    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
      number.append(st.nextToken());
    }

    phoneNumber = number.toString();
    return phoneNumber;
  }

  public static boolean palindromeTest(String pNumber)
  {
    StringBuffer reversedNumber = new StringBuffer(pNumber);
    reversedNumber.reverse().toString();

    if(pNumber.equals(reversedNumber))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't assign the value returned by `reversedNumber.reverse().toString()`to `reversedNumber`.

Do
`String reversedNumberString = reversedNumber.reverse().toString();`

And by the way, you can just return
`return pNumber.equals(reversedNumber);` - the if/else statement is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank's man. So reversedNumber remained a StringBuffer object and I had to make a string variable and convert it that way. Also thanks for the return tip.

Comment: No problem :-)
So I guess you can close the question now

Comment: How do you close it I can't seem to find it? Accepting the answer is not working for some reason? NVM it's working now, very odd